# read .p7m file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, smime

how to retrieve all information for .P7M file using c# application.
sample .p7m file :
please if possible then give me code or sample example link

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha1; boundary="----6975263937A7DDC0C0034052D76E8275"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------6975263937A7DDC0C0034052D76E8275
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: MVCI - Restart Needed a
X-Relevance-Evaluation-Period: 0:0:1
X-Relevance-Child-Evaluation-Period: 0:0:1
Content-Type: multipart/digest; boundary="AD27641"

--AD27641

Subject: MVCI - Restart Needed a
X-Relevant-When: pending restart and (not exists file "C:\Windows\System32\No_Reboot.txt")
X-Fixlet-ID: 27641
X-Fixlet-Category: Computer Support
X-Fixlet-Source: BigFix
X-Fixlet-Source-Severity: Moderate
X-Fixlet-Source-ID: <Unspecified>
X-Fixlet-Source-Release-Date: 9/12/2006
X-Fixlet-Download-Size: 0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="F27641"

--F27641
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<custom>
--F27641
Content-id: Action1
Content-Type: application/x-Fixlet-Windows-Shell

// only run this action on computers that are not locked
continue if {not locked of action lock state}

restart
action requires restart

// only run this action on computers that are not locked
continue if {not locked of action lock state}

action parameter query "RestartWaitTime" with description "Please enter the number of seconds to wait after warning the user before forcing a restart on the computer:"

restart {parameter "RestartWaitTime" of action}
action requires restart

--F27641--

--AD27641--

------6975263937A7DDC0C0034052D76E8275
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIC7QYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIC3jCCAtoCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3
DQEHATGCArkwggK1AgEBMIIBXTCCAVYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAi0tMRQwEgYDVQQDEwtC
cmlhbiBKb25lczERMA8GA1UECBQIPE5PREFUQT4xETAPBgNVBAcUCDxOT0RBVEE+
MSUwIwYDVQQKExxNYXJyaW90dCBWYWNhdGlvbiBDbHViIEludCdsMQowCAYDVQQL
EwEtMSswKQYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhxicmlhbi5qb25lc0B2YWNhdGlvbmNsdWIuY29t
MYGqMBAGA1UEKRMJSGFzaDpzaGExMDEGA1UEKRMqU2VydmVyOkxBTEZJTVZCRjEu
TVYuTUFSUkNPUlAuTUFSUklPVFQuQ09NMB0GA1UEKRMWTGljZW5zZUFsbG9jYXRp
b246NDk1MDAbBgNVBCkTFEN1c3RvbUFjdGlvbnM6RW5hYmxlMCcGA1UEKRMgQ3Vz
dG9tUmV0cmlldmVkUHJvcGVydGllczpFbmFibGUCARIwCQYFKw4DAhoFAKCBsTAY
BgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBTEPFw0wNjEwMTYx
ODE5MTRaMCMGCSqGSIb3DQEJBDEWBBRSsDje+FssF4dum8OfDyhrvlqYtjBSBgkq
hkiG9w0BCQ8xRTBDMAoGCCqGSIb3DQMHMA4GCCqGSIb3DQMCAgIAgDANBggqhkiG
9w0DAgIBQDAHBgUrDgMCBzANBggqhkiG9w0DAgIBKDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASB
gOa3bY4oDVLwJ1LXv4YGJuWI7yrRnAPJu+CUJNB9VE40FVddLyZAgya4TtxVSxap
fB0/molXCbPcmG5eqNS8CZ/BPZtBbyTFai+hQNyhxSxvbvvn4xoCCtvftLj1UkVx
9ftCqSJKSeIWUk0jnQTU/pGrySOpXeJewqgRg06Sxejf

------6975263937A7DDC0C0034052D76E8275--

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            !÷Rž»¶ÛSccöê'˜az&¶¹C÷sˆâŒßjJÇIÓt*¶ók=;^ÀœË  ØMöšÐåÌù˜=pN…>á0'¶rjŠ"úžìŽä¨ýà˜Üðö<*%aÐ0êæS9ä‡“.$œG¿ˆÁWäà•)—L‡ënhQ'ú
ÎsÆRã±ùÎ"2A¾T¢ˆ³¿éy¢öK±–Ã‹'*Ì®  _%í#ÝRÖâÒÉX‰<u^N‡pÊ×DÚCóu°¼˜–E¢W•|^ç^e¢øákÎØ†@o¬ymíOX‚°žÏ\ƒhæ£F&Eô=´sx‹bÒ2!¢:¾Å¶œ¸¦€‡5Ž×ö$üd-CsÖðºHöNk+'.…š¡³à,§áßIŒ%œ”ð‹<$áÀ !hÏ¸¹!…*e´Ô(¯t¤u6 OÐKFLò™üå”!¿Õ„MÝ÷>Þ*yŽR:ÛOtÇüHeš3Ÿì‡~C0¥;L9‘ó0%ìû±Ò ¿no,e?‹õñcmO7ÒXZ*÷n­    ‘,ÈsÅç*ìE¡(§#\ãOax¬Ç¨’ˆøÞ¢™ÀçÌ*¸(^´-ùÝÍOä6Ø"‘Ù]ŒÕŒ¶R*‹†'ð˜ÅYŒìsˆ²’o[VáMûV•È%kÊNi5K8±–KÓ‡ÃeÈVk5·†lÆ7lŠü»¬ƒýÎ‚ÃE[íD¡O)|Í —)#æó ÚübcÀv…€‰*¼‹5ó(ìÄtôù±ÐÔ^CS|T”f2£7Æ²ÕnÃDV_;?«Àþsy
2•^;=;002_tdqX¬«†@´iòQ‘TDª
2ªÀ4ªb(äÂ‹
 æöE8ý|,~ÊgU@÷eÉö•É£Spù í©L~T¢DÔÉÜcñ#”ˆ‚š]ƒ=ŽáïˆË9% RÒô3­UìIˆÁó}¨ÚîïÓºÁWÀ„;‚~ÒÇBæ#Íi}bI¤îh¾•2EŸ NÙüTâ÷;Ü1!T “¡2P¦q/+"G®LÙ)KÉÁ¤êR|…#UIÌgê¹Ý‚u¥°ç:#Í1ÝF7ŒPTB{ph882­–å“U$‹LÛù\œ¢êgõ\lGt˜¨æ˜Ph676µŸôÞÝ{ÝQU@Èn¤lT+'ïŒ´Þlô‹Å‚ž<5t„CÊl'ô”—ïí#×¹B]s©\òÀ`;ÚŠ‘ÆrÎäô7Ggg—zòÚ¸Þ;>;K~Å‘. o’’{X-˜É#•žM«nÛåhMò®[ž?h
ÒÉÿˆ´ßï`T@ìûv÷Æ´nä‹o}d¹†ÕŸ2k.•Fu…åNã]í$YÔµéŽz¾ÀPmÐúÔgù/3Ñã20õ¤‘zÆ‘/yzxñüìñ¿ž =[uþ F çW
Â%uÙGj¤‘…¡²¯¡‚®@®–úeñgù†¥F¶4v‘°ÑõÀŸ0Ýl`Ú@@0óçl¿Éø€¸Í
:ñ{çülCHÑÄ¤œÔÇ¦<S¸[@À˜õ=}“ÙÍ‘±”±â=bYoãËKm?~A˜ô&kbhÝ¸DuÔÿ½£ÙÿÙÙ£¯]¿&bÊüâY(@&ô€°fÕHæßÉTß–ß +|æ­ºQtÁYŠ«Š+‘Êû¼Ác4îµ{uiC¼œ¯4
”Dµ]^R
Œ.€8~wJì)N]“¥ûpÚv»Þ†¢øÔL5:[°¦|RÑ/gýÿ[öRÜáÜuÿçRR=€R—Œ¨7Ç&¯;?2:-¯í¹|lDšÑŽßÇÇ£Ù@P°¶žŸ¹xýhìÿ´*Ž‡`~£¤£2BŸ±W£óÚOøÒ$½u‰[Zgq\‚>ÇRÐýx$ŠYeW@çÀE¦Ë¨Dä}‘Ä2µ)Ä«`³afÙiõPèœüv¹y-Ž}}-¨Yˆ†iù¹[Þ#º¢ð<Üg–R÷ÚàÆ»KÀˆÔsÖD†DÂ
ñíìÆû´e¹Õ¸£ÑWÀ¼0À
Ð)Ñ.†ÝP
hÑõ¸À”“ë=$b¹ÍøÜÝùÍ¢Œ‡RñO][.ñ ‡Ð¼ogûº™€ÍÍ¼@”=¼0‡Ð$õjÍÀ”Ú$ûœÚºäa‘PR+K¿¿ÊS zTZHmý•ß\òNø¸ý7àƒT:¥¿…ìõU·o35÷þµ£¡ÇÎÞë¿v_5+!Çhtïš'¿ÊzppY÷¦m™¸È‹Z‚Y’xdÊ‹ÔÚ™ðç¿¿«©ùl9%¦yeÖÞ·RvxKHG‘Òqô;(ÓuáÂ»JNô¡{AEþ}\9Ãý{ôYriþ‘FÏûr &„ò­ô€òU¢ÒÃºkà¾&ƒ>žý€ibuJôžUOŒ¶“C€uIßçªgã‰”r¾w”õYÚhŸ%dîáôÆò7Ÿe?ZÐ¦d‰¸À×¦ê´lø”Oë™ëxâp
```

please give replay back if any suggetion and any quetion then tell me .
i am waiting for replay .

Comment: it would be helpful if you told us what the code you posted actually is

Comment: post in not any code it's a sample file of .p7m

Comment: how to retrieve all information from .p7m file? means parsing p7m file.

Comment: I see, because getting the information from the file, is pretty easy; parsing it on the other hand is a different kind of beast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to the non-free/non-open source solutions posted above, I might suggest taking a look at my free/open source S/MIME library: [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit)

To handle your input data, you'd do something like this:

```
var entity = MimeEntity.Load (stream);

if (entity is MultipartSigned) {
    var signed = (MultipartSigned) entity;

    foreach (var signature in signed.Verify ()) {
        try {
            bool valid = signature.Verify ();

            // If valid is true, then it signifies that the signed content has
            // not been modified since this particular signer signed the content.
            //
            // However, if it is false, then it indicates that the signed content
            // has been modified.
        } catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException) {
            // There was an error verifying the signature.
        }

        // If you'd like to get a copy of the certificate used for signing,
        // you could do this:
        var wrapper = (SecureMimeDigitalCertificate) signature.Certificate;
        var cert = wrapper.Certificate;

        // The cert is a BouncyCastle X509Certificate, so if you want to convert
        // it to a System.Security X509Certificate2, you can do this:
        var x509certificate2 = new X509Certificate2 (cert.GetEncoded ());
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use MimeKit library.

Comment: and one other think using "System.Security.Cryptography" is free library.

Comment: Yes, System.Security is also a free library... but it won't parse the MIME data for you (which you need to do in order to get at the data).

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide source code to parse & handle the same MIME data you provided in your question. MimeKit's main GitHub page (identical to the README) documents how to handle S/MIME signed and encrypted data as well.

Answer (score 2):

please also check this way :
more information related to code: http://www.logue.com.ar/blog/2010/03/encryption-and-decryption-with-x-509-certificates/

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.IO;

namespace Logue.Library.Cryptography
{
public static class CryptographyHelper
{
    #region Public methods
    public static string Encrypt(string fullMessage, string certificateName)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate(certificateName);

        string base64DecryptedContent = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fullMessage));
        base64DecryptedContent = ChunkContent(base64DecryptedContent, 76);
        base64DecryptedContent = EnvelopeBase64(base64DecryptedContent);

        byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64DecryptedContent);

        Oid contentOid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1", "PKCS 7 Data");
        Oid algorithmOid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.3.2", "rc2");
        AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmIdentifier = new AlgorithmIdentifier(algorithmOid);
        ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(contentOid, contentBytes);
        EnvelopedCms envelope = new EnvelopedCms(SubjectIdentifierType.NoSignature, content, algorithmIdentifier);

        envelope.Encrypt(new CmsRecipient(certificate));
        byte[] encryptedBytes = envelope.Encode();

        string encryptedContent = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);

        encryptedContent = ChunkContent(encryptedContent, 76);
        string result = EnvelopEncryptedContent(encryptedContent);

        return result;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string fullMessage)
    {
        string messageContent = GetContentInBase64(fullMessage);

        // Load envelope and decrypt
        EnvelopedCms envelope = new EnvelopedCms();
        envelope.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(messageContent));
        envelope.Decrypt();

        // Get original bytes
        byte[] decryptedBytes = envelope.ContentInfo.Content;
        string decryptedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBytes);

        // Get processed Base64 content
        byte[] decryptedContentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(GetContentInBase64(decryptedText));
        string decryptedContentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedContentBytes);

        return decryptedContentText;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private static string ChunkContent(string encryptedContent, int chunkSize)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(encryptedContent);

        int position = 0;
        char[] buffer = new char[chunkSize];

        while (position < encryptedContent.Length)
        {
            if (encryptedContent.Length - (position + chunkSize) < 0)
            chunkSize = encryptedContent.Length - position;
            sb.Append(encryptedContent.Substring(position, chunkSize));
            sb.Append("rn");
            position += chunkSize;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static string EnvelopEncryptedContent(string encryptedContent)
    {
        return CryptographyResources.ENCRYPTED_TEMPLATE.Replace("[REPLACE]", encryptedContent);
    }

    private static string EnvelopeBase64(string content)
    {
        return CryptographyResources.BASE64_TEMPLATE.Replace("[REPLACE]", content);
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string certificateName)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Where(cert => cert.Subject.IndexOf(certificateName) >= 0).FirstOrDefault();
        if (certificate == null)
        throw new Exception("Certificate " + certificateName + " not found.");

        return certificate;
    }

    private static string GetContentInBase64(string fullMessage)
    {
        string contentSeparator = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        int startIndex = fullMessage.IndexOf(contentSeparator) + contentSeparator.Length;
        int endIndex = fullMessage.Length - 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string[] lines = fullMessage.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        sb.Append(line);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an S/MIME message. You need to parse the S/MIME message, then decode the attachment. .NET doesn't offer S/MIME parsing functionality out of the box, so you need to use some third-party library - either something mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629206/ews-retrieving-attachments-from-signed-emails) or [Rebex](https://rebex.net/secure-mail.net/) or our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-mime.php) for parsing the message.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to parse the BigFix (aka IBM Tivoli Endpoint Manager) Fixlet directly from the file, there is a much easier way. Simply use the BigFix REST API to query the components of the Fixlet individually. You can see examples of how to do this on the IBM forums (along with example C# code):
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Tivoli%20Endpoint%20Manager/page/REST%20API