# Failing to retrieve attachments from EWS server

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have a file attachment synching feature that is used by an Outlook add-in (OfficeJS). The EWS token and URL are fetched using [3] and [4]

We fetch attachments using EWS SOAP API calls detailed here[2]. However, we have noticed that some of these calls fail randomly and will succeed in subsequent retries. I do not think this is related to signed emails [1]. Is there a rate limit on the EWS SOAP API calls?

EDIT:

The response returned by a direct SOAP request to the EWS endpoint:

```
                <m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
                <m:MessageText>The specified attachment Id is invalid.</m:MessageText>
                <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidAttachmentId</m:ResponseCode>
                <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
                <m:Attachments/>
            </m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage>
```

**Reference**

[1] [EWS: Retrieving attachments from signed emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629206/ews-retrieving-attachments-from-signed-emails)

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item#use-ews-to-get-the-attachments

[3]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox#ewsurl-string

[4] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox#getcallbacktokenasyncoptions-callback

Comment: Is there any error shown on the response when it fails - like in the response headers / body?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. It just returns an empty body.

Comment: Did you also check the response headers?  Sometimes there are error messages inside of the response headers.

Comment: @BrianClink I updated the question with the error response.